# Tiktok analytics and location data

Tags: google-analytics, amazon-aws, wix

I am trying to figure out how effective my ad-spend on Tiktok is, but I am having an issue where there is a really big discrepancy between all my analytic sources vis-a-vis user locations.

**Question:** How accurate are Tiktok DMAs?

**Information:**
I have an app hosted on AWS that is tracked using Google Analytics. Both of these sources of information claim that about 50% of my traffic / users (over the past 5 days) are based in the US.

I ran an ad-campaign on Tiktok that was specifically directed at a US audience. The ad opens a wix.com site before redirecting to my app. Wix.com data tracking says that 100% of the traffic is from the US.

These two results are directly contradictory.

**Hypothesis 1:** The fact that tiktok and wix are saying the same thing can be explained by the fact that the browser is the Tiktok Browser. So, if Tiktok thinks you're in the US, presumably it will pass that information on to Wix. (who knows why Wix has specifics like city, though)

**Hypothesis 2:** It is believable that people want to trick Tiktok into thinking they are in the US - most likely for content preferences. I have seen *some* information on the internet to back this up, but not really enough to justify the magnitude of people that would need to be doing this.

Any experience or even thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated!